# Flask start new thread - RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am using flask to run my long process that already related to session which hold user id and other information. i try to use new thread with both following methods but still got error 'RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.'

Method 1

```
import threading
Thread(target=lambda: fn(**args)).start()
```

Method 2

```
import thread
thread.start_new_thread(fn, (), args)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use session inside thread you have to start that thread from bridge with copy_current_request_context

```
from flask import copy_current_request_context
@copy_current_request_context
def ctx_bridge():
    fn(**args)
Thread(target=ctx_bridge).start()
```